# DateTime in php with timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-5.3

I have a question. I try to use datetime in php.
I did :

```
$now = new \DateTime();
```

When I print_r the `$now` I have :

```
DateTime Object
(
  [date] => 2016-12-01 05:55:01
  [timezone_type] => 3
  [timezone] => Europe/Helsinki
)
```

When I look at clock I have `16:05`. I need to set the timezone ? I want to use Bucharest timezone. How I can get the right date and hour ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 23):

You have two ways to set right timezone. It is object way and procedural way.

---

**Examples**

**Object**

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
echo $datetime->format('F d, Y H:i');
```

**Procedural**

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bucharest");
$date = date('F d, Y H:i');
echo $date;
```

---

**Manuals**

- [PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [PHP: DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [PHP: DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetimezone.php)

---

**Update**

Check code below, may it will work for you:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
echo $datetime->format('F d, Y H:i');
?>
```

Comment: It gives `December 01, 2016 16:35`, and that's time in Bucharest now.

Comment: I got `December 01, 2016 06:25
`

Comment: Garsienica, not work :( I got `December 01, 2016 06:29`

Comment: Strange... it works there: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48cfb8f22a92310f7556e40f02df8fb71372dad6

Answer (score 12):

There are [examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), you can set the timezone on the instantiation of the DateTime class like this

```
$now = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest'));
```

Comment: I have this : `DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-12-01 06:09:43
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Bucharest
)
`

Comment: But the hour now is `16:22`

Comment: The time in Bucharest is 16:22 @ UTC 14:22

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Then you are doing something else other than what you have shown us to the `$now` variable

Comment: I use a virtual machine, and this machine have linux

Comment: And this machine have : `Thu Dec  1 06:32:44 EET 2016`

Comment: it's a way to get the date not depending OS

Answer (score 2):

put this line of code above your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $datetime = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( "Europe/Bucharest" ) );

    echo $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

[Demo repl.it](https://repl.it/@antelove19/DateTime-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimezone()` method of `DateTime` class to set the timezone to Europe/Bucharest, like this:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest'));
```

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php