# Fixing wrong dates in Laravel/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I've realized my application is writing dates the day before they are indicated (For example, when inserting dates within a spreadsheet file import). I set the local timezone once and now all dates are 4 hours earlier and the day before. How can I fix these so that it doesn't happen again.

`config/app.php says: 'timezone' => 'America/Santiago'`

(When I type `now()` on `tinker` date and time are right).

Should I leave it as `'UTC'`? Was that the cause?

What do I do with the already written dates set at `20:00:00` the day before?

Comment: Might need to see the code related to the spreadsheet exports. Or are you saying you've corrected the issue but now just need to correct past data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you correctly. If you can show some sample data and the desired output, that would be helpful to understand.

Comment: PHP is transforming a date to my timezone: For instance, 2019-07-18 00:00:00 to 2019-07-17 20:00:00.

Comment: If I type now() it's understandable that it uses my timezone but if I insert a date I don't want it to convert it to anything else.

Comment: Think you are looking for [`DateTune::SetTimezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php). Maybe look at top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912701/datetime-in-php-with-timezone